# Best practise building a realtime geospatial application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, geospatial

I like to build a backend for a geobased multiplayer game. After a long time of research i figured out that NodeJS and MongoDB are the best approach doing this (because of MongoDBs 2d indexing possibilities and geoJson support).

---

Basic functionality I need is that users can see each other on their mobile app (on a map). To avoid polling the database, I decided to use websockets to send the current position of a user to the server. 
But, the problem is the other way round: How can I figure out when a location of a user has changed in the database? Is polling (e.g. every 5 seconds) here an adequate solution? For example:

```
    db.places.find(
   {
     location:
       { $near :
          {
            $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [ -73.9667, 40.78 ] },
            $minDistance: 1000,
            $maxDistance: 5000
          }
       }
   }
)
```

Or when I try storing the location data of all active users in RAM, then the app can not scale over multiple node instances, right?

Comment: node is definitely the right choice, but I recommend taking a look at [RethinkDB](http://rethinkdb.com/). It has [geo indexes](http://rethinkdb.com/docs/geo-support/javascript/) and more important [realtime changes feed](http://rethinkdb.com/docs/changefeeds/javascript/). It's literally easier than taking candy from a baby.